# firing two google analytics events, only the first one is saved in GA

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I'm firing 2 GA events after another.
Only the first one is stored in GA.

Here's the function call. I've made a separate service for my tracking:

```
    Analytics.TrackEvent('MijnTijdschriften', 'DownloadPauze', folioItemView.folio.title + "-" + folioItemView.folio.folioNumber);
    Analytics.TrackEvent('DownloadTijdPauze', Analytics.CalculateTime(folioItemView.folio.productId), folioItemView.folio.title + "-" + folioItemView.folio.folioNumber);
```

The actual TrackEvent function looks like this:

```
    GoogleAnalyticsAccounts.forEach(function(entry) {
        var prefix = getGoogleAnalyticsAccountPrefix(entry);
        _gaq.push([entry]);
        _gaq.push([prefix + '_trackEvent', action, label, value, 0, false]);
    });
```

My idea is that the second call send a number to GA instead of a textual value. 
or if the CalculateTime returns null, the call just isn't happening.
Or does there need to be a delay between events ...

any insight would be helpful!

Thanks

Mario

Comment: You can send multiple events at once, do you see both events being sent to GA?

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the Events Per session limit if you are using ga.js:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#implementationConsiderations

Here's the portion that applies:

In addition to general  collection limits and quotas, the following limit applies to event tracking in ga.js:
**•The first 10 event hits sent to Google Analytics are tracked immediately, thereafter tracking is rate limited to one event hit per second.**

If you're triggering more than 10 events on a page, you may be butting up against the 1 per second limit when you send two in a row immediately like that.